# Avoid duplicate rows in phonegap database

Tags: sql, database, cordova

I have a database with a single column and create it like this

```
function populateDB(tx){
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RESULT(result, UNIQUE(result))');  
}
```

however, when I want to write objects into the table, I get the error:

> could not execute statement (19 constraint failed)

The error only appears when I add the NOT NULL and PRIMARY KEY to the set-Up. Without it, it keeps writing duplicates in my database (I fill the database with data from a webservice on startup of a phonegap iOS application, so I want to catch duplicate rows on database level)

At first I had only "PRIMARY KEY" in it, and because the error says something about constraints, I was assuming the primary key has to be "NOT NULL", adding it to the code, I still got the same error.

how can I solve this. thanks in advance

**edit**: Maybe it´s important for you to know that I write stringyfied JSON Objects into the results column.

**edit**: I insert the object in this function. Basically I do it one by one:

```
this.save = function(){
    db.transaction (function(transaction){
        object = $.toJSON(self);
        object = encodeURI(object);
        transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO RESULT (result) VALUES ("'+object+'")');
        },
        errorCB, 
        successCB
    );
}
```

**edit**: I updated my set up table code. The error doesnt occur on every row, but the objects are actually unique.

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` enforces a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`.  So that's the constraint you're failing with your duplicates.  To solve your problem, however, we need to know how you are inserting your data.  One row at a time, a bulk insert, from another table, etc, etc?

Comment: 19, that's some kind of record? :P

Comment: have you dropped and recreated your table after making the changes in definition?? `19` constraint violation error is basically serving your purpose by generating the error for the data which is already there in the table.

Comment: dhaval, yes I drop the table and the error occurs

Comment: the problem was in the .save() method. Sorry for bothering you guys. @aF. : No, it´s not a record, I only listen to mp3s.

Answer (score 0):

"IF NOT EXISTS" is the catch here. You get constraint failed when you use conditions like "IF NOT EXISTS" or "REPLACE", "IGNORE" etc in SQLite queries.

Suppose, you're trying to create a table that already exists, then the constraint (here not creating the table again if it already exist) fails and hence the query fails (which you actually want - you dont want to duplicate the tables right?) and gives you the error constraint failed.

You may get a similar error on INSERT or REPLACE, INSERT or IGNORE, etc...